# React Redux routing just refreshes

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have to redirect users after logging in, to the main component of the app. I am using redux to manage states.

I tried to change my login method like this from [this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5237) thread:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { push } from 'react-router-redux'
import { API_URL } from '../utils/apiUrl'

export const loginUser = creds => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(loginRequest(creds))

    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: API_URL + "/auth_token",
      data: { auth: creds }
    }).then(res => {

       dispatch(push('/home')) /* dispatch an action that changes the browser history */ 

      })

    }).catch(err =>
      dispatch(loginFailure('Wrong email/password combination'))
    )
  }
}
```

So in my case it looks something like this:

```
export function authenticate(user, password) {
        var data = {
            "username" : user,
            "password": password
        };
        return function(dispatch) {
            return axios({
                url: 'someserver:xxxx/login',
                timeout: 20000,
                method: 'POST',
                data: data,               
            }).then(function(response) {
                dispatch(loggedIn(response.data.token));
            }).then(res => {
                dispatch(push('/main'));    <------ route to main page
            }).catch(function(error) {
                if (error.response) {
                    // DEBUGGING
                    console.log(error.response.data);
                    console.log(error.response.status);
                    console.log(error.response.headers);
                }
            })
        }
    }
    const loggedIn = (token) => ({
        type: "LOGIN",
        token
    })
```

App.js looks like this:

```
render() {
    return (     
      <Router>
        <div style={{textAlign : 'center'}}>
        <Route path="/main" component={Main}/>
          <img src={Logo} alt="fireSpot"/>
          <p style={{paddingTop: '2%'}}>LOGIN</p>
          <form>
              <TextField
                id="username"
                label="USERNAME"
                value={this.state.username}
                onChange={(event) => this.handleUsername(event)}
                margin="normal"
              /> <br />
              <TextField
                value={this.state.password}
                onChange={(event) => this.handlePassword(event)}
                id="password"
                label="PASSWORD"
                type="password"
                autoComplete="current-password"
                margin="normal"
              />
              <br />

              <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <Button
                  onClick={
                    this.handleSubmit
                  }                    
                  disabled={!this.validateForm()}
                  type="submit"
                  variant="raised"
                  color="secondary"
                >
                Anmelden
              </Button>

            </MuiThemeProvider>
          </form>
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

The `handleSubmit` method:

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.login();
}
```

And the `mapDispatchToProps`:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return { 
    login : function() {
      dispatch(authenticate(this.state.username, this.state.password));
    }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

The login works. I can even print the response I get: `{type: "@@router/CALL_HISTORY_METHOD", payload: {…}}`, but nothing happens.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Meanwhile I added to App.js

```
handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    await this.props.login();
    this.props.history.push('/main')


}
```

and wrapped everything in the export in App.js with `withRouter`:

```
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App));
```

I changed the `ReactDOM.render(<App store={store}/>...` line to

```
ReactDOM.render(<Router><div><App store={store} /> </div></Router>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

which got rid of the `A <Router> may have only one child element` error. Now it seems to redirect to somewhere, but it just ends up in:

`Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(Main)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to "Connect(Main)".`

**EDIT 2:**

I imported Provider and passed `store` as `props` to it and now it works.

```
ReactDOM.render(
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
        <div>
            <App store={store} /> 
        </div>
    </Router>
</Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Only issue right now is, that it just adds the content of `Main` OVER the login fields. Any ideas?

**EDIT 3:**
I removed everything related to `Router` from `App.js` and edited the `index.js` file like this.

```
<Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
        <div>
            <Route exact path="/" component={App}/>
            <Route path="/main" component={Main}/> 
        </div>
    </Router>
</Provider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

It solved the stacking components issue after logging in. I don't know how to return something from `login` so that the app doesn't advance to `Main` if the credentials are wrong, as @ivica.moke wrote in his comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make login async, and await response from login, then after that process completes push to '/main'. You can even return something from login() action and based of response even push to main (if success) or force to enter valid credentials (if not logged in successfully).

```
handleSubmit =async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    await this.props.login();
    this.props.history.push('/main');
}
```

**EDIT**
in your API call with `axios`, your server will hopefully return some status code. Inside `.then` from `axios`where you recieve `res` you can check for that status code (check with console.log(res)) to see what your API returns. then just from that `.then` return `res` or `res.status`.

```
axios.post(url,data)
   .then(res => {
  // here you check status code from API response
  // and return response or it's status code
  return res;
})
   .catch(error => {
  //if error meaning not statusCode 200 (login failed for some reason)
  return error;
});
```

**inside handleSubmit**

```
handleSubmit =async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const res = await this.props.login();
        // this res is what you get from action
        // for example
        if(res.status === 200){
        // 200(status ok) meaning successful login
        this.props.history.push('/main');
        }
        else {
        // login failed
        }
}
```

I hope that makes it a bit clearer.

Comment: Cool, I didn't know I could use `async` like that. I did try this but I am getting an error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` - Tried adding `withRouter(App)` but I need to have store there since I am accessing variables from it.

Comment: Okay, I wrapped it like this `export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App));` But I'm still getting `You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>
`

Comment: Also added `ReactDOM.render(<Router><App store={store} /> </Router>, document.getElementById('root'));` to `index.js` and now I am getting `A <Router> may have only one child element` which doesn't make any sense, since there is only `<App>` embedded.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "You can even return something from login() action and based of response even push to main (if success) or force to enter valid credentials (if not logged in successfully)."? @ivica.moke

Comment: Cool, that makes a lot of sense! I will accept your reply as the answer since I couldn't have solved this without knowing about `async` and `await`. Thanks! Btw. I had to write `login` like this, since the other rest calls wouldn't wait for `login` : `login : async function() ` and inside it `await dispatch(authenticate(username, password))` and then add a bunch of `then( () => dispatch(fetchSomething))` for the rest.